# if condition always returning False

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am writing a [powershell-v2.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v2.0) script. The script contains a function to set environment variable. The function is as follows:

```
function SetSvnEnvironmentVariable($path)
{
    # Get the Path environment variable
    $pathVar = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")

    # Check if path environment variable already contains the path to be added
    if(-Not ($pathVar -like $path))
    {
        $pathVar += $path
        [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",$pathVar, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
    }
}
```

The `$path` variable contains the path to be added to the PATH environment variable.

The problem I am facing is, even though `$path` is a substring of `$pathVar`, the if condition always returns `False`.

Following are the values of `$pathVar` and `$path`.

**`$pathVar`**:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2009b\bin\win32;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin

**`$path`**:

> ;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a wildcard fixed my problem. `-like` operator without a wildcard compared the strings if they were equal and hence always returned `False`.

By changing the `if` condition as follows, the `if` condition returns `True`:

```
if(-Not ($pathVar -like "*$path*"))
{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using wildcard or regular expression matches for this kind of check bears the risk of getting false positives if the path already contains a subfolder of the folder you want to add. It's better to split the value of the environment variable at semicolons and use the `-contains`/`-notcontains` operator to check if the resulting array does or doesn't contain the item you want to add:

```
function SetSvnEnvironmentVariable($path)
{
    $pathVar = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User')

    if ($pathVar.Split(';') -notcontains $path))
    {
        $pathVar += ";$path"
        [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $pathVar, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
    }
}
```

Note that `$path` should not be specified with a leading (or trailing) semicolon.

Comment: Look at the value of $path which I have mentioned in the question

Comment: @Abhishek Look at the note at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Would that not add another semicolon to the starting of $path?

Comment: @Abhishek It produces the exact same result as your code, only that `$path` here is actually a path and not "a path plus something else". Don't make separators part of your variables unless you have rather compelling reasons to do so.